# More eclipse insanity. How to keep the logcat view from monopolizing during debug session

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse decides for me and others that if the logcat screen is open then when activity occurs during a debug the screen should switch from debug to logcat!  Thanks eclipse, nice user friendly logic there. No need to look at variable values, not while there is stuff happening in logcat.  Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening.

Update: Please note, I have never requested or modified the settings related to logcat.

Comment: Someone should upvote this. It will save others a lot of frustration and reduced productivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferences > Android > LogCat > either uncheck "Switch Perspective" or "Monitor logcat for messages from applications in workspace", I imagine, whichever fits your workflow better.